# Checkbox doesn't enable fields Knockout

Tags: checkbox, knockout.js, isenabled

I'm trying to set enabled true for "SetOutputCurrentPPLowValue" & "SetOutputCurrentPPHighValue" when "SetAlarmValues" is checked. I have the following code, for this issue:

The fields are disabled when the page is loaded but when the "SetAlarmValues" is checked, they stay disabled. I'm not sure why. Please help!

```
  <!-- ko if: $root.regData -->
     <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <label for="SetAlarmValues" class="control-label">@MSL.Core.Resource.Models.Well.SetAlarmValues:</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: $root.regData().setAlarmValues" class="large-check registration" id="SetAlarmValuesCheck" title="@MSL.Core.Resource.Models.Well.SetAlarmValues" />
    
                </div>
               
            </div>
    
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <label for="SetOutputCurrentPP" class="control-label">Set Output Current PP:</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
    
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-1">                    
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-5 form-inline">
                        <label for="SetOutputCurrentPPLowValue" class="control-label">@MSL.Core.Resource.Models.Well.OutputCurrentPPLowValue: </label>&nbsp;
    
                        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: $root.regData().setOutputCurrentPPLowValue, enable:  $root.regData().setAlarmValues()" class="large-check registration" id="SetOutputCurrentPPLowValue" title="@MSL.Core.Resource.Models.Well.SetOutputCurrentPPLowValue" />
                        <input type="text" id="OutputCurrentPPLowValue" data-bind="value: $root.regData().outputCurrentPPLowValue, enable: $root.regData().setOutputCurrentPPLowValue" class="form-control" maxlength="30" />
    
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br />
    
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-1">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-5 form-inline">
                        <label for="SetOutputCurrentPPHighValue" class="control-label">@MSL.Core.Resource.Models.Well.OutputCurrentPPHighValue:</label>
    
                        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: $root.regData().setOutputCurrentPPHighValue, enable: $root.regData().setAlarmValues()" class="large-check registration" id="SetOutputCurrentPPHighValue" title="@MSL.Core.Resource.Models.Well.SetOutputCurrentPPHighValue" />
                        <input type="text" id="OutputCurrentPPHighValue" data-bind="value: $root.regData().outputCurrentPPHighValue, enable: $root.regData().setOutputCurrentPPHighValue" class="form-control" maxlength="30" />
    
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

         <!-- /ko -->
```

And this is the script:

```
function Registration() {
    var self = this;
    //Alarms
    self.setAlarmValues = ko.observable(false);
    self.setOutputCurrentPPLowValue = ko.observable(false);
    self.setOutputCurrentPPHighValue = ko.observable(false);
    self.outputCurrentPPLowValue = ko.observable("");
    self.outputCurrentPPHighValue = ko.observable("");

}



var registerVM = function (countryListJSON, companyListJSON, wellStatusListJSON, territoryListJSON) {
    self = this;

    self.validation = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.savingData = ko.observable(false);
    self.regData = ko.observable(new Registration());
}
```

Comment: use `with` binding get rid if redundant code. code looks fine, if u can put up a working sample(fiddle) happy to help.

Comment: @supercool I've made a fiddle with the above code and it is working. But in Visual studio it isn't. Very annoying. The thing is `with` will hide everything as far as I know but I want it to show but be enabled only when the checkboxes are checked or not. Here is the fiddle: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/micuraluca/esn904yt/)

Comment: @supercool I tried using `with` binding which again works on fiddle but not in mine! I can't figure out what's wrong. Here is the fiddle for this binding: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/micuraluca/k7gmjL9f/)

Comment: VS is nothing to do with the issue. still `with` is not properly used refer this https://jsfiddle.net/8vwqzjnh/ . `with` creates new context where children can refer to.

Comment: @supercool that didn't work either. So I tried with iCheck. Here is the fiddle: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/micuraluca/xdpu0cyj/5/) but for some reason this is the only code that won't work in fiddle but it actually works on my local.

Answer (score 0):

In your code i see this statement- enable:  $root.regData().setAlarmValues(), and the setAlarmValues value is been set to false. It will only enabled once you set the value of the field setAlarmValues to true. But as you mentioned once the checkbox is checked please make sure to check if the value is still false or is it changed to True.

Comment: I added a console log and the value doesn't change when I check the checkbox. I don't know why.

Comment: update your data-bind like this 
data-bind="checked: $root.regData().setAlarmValues, click: UpdateValue, clickBubble: false".   
And add the following to your model      
self.UpdateValue= (item) => {
        event.stopPropagation();
        return true;
    };

Comment: this didn't work either. I also tried with `event: {change: $root.setChanged}` & `self.setChanged = function () {
        self.regData().setAlarmValues(true);
    }` but didn't work either. Everything works in fiddle but not in VS.

Comment: Have you added this (clickBubble: false) to your dat-bind ??

Comment: Yes, I have. The only thing which worked is when I tried with iCheck. Here is the fiddle: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/micuraluca/xdpu0cyj/5/) but for some reason this is the only code that won't work in fiddle but it actually works on my local.