# iCheck and knockout - enable binding doesn't show dependent checkbox as enabled

Tags: javascript, checkbox, knockout.js, icheck

I have a checkbox for setAlarmValues that works fine. But when checked, the SetOutputCurrentPPLowValue & SetOutputCurrentPPHighValue checkboxed don't show like they are enabled. They can be clicked if the setAlarmValues is checked but they are greyed out and the cursor doesn't change on hover. When checking the element I can see it gets disabled or enabled but the class remains the same: icheckbox_square-blue disabled. I'm guessing this is the reason it doesn't work properly but how can I change it dynamically?

Here is a picture of how it looks like at the moment:

I am trying to make the Low value and High value checkboxes to look like they are enabled (blue in this case).

[image: checkbox]

```
  <!-- ko if: $root.regData -->

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <label for="SetAlarmValues" class="control-label">Set Alarm Values:</label>
      <input type="checkbox" data-bind="iCheck: $root.regData().setAlarmValues" class="large-check" id="SetAlarmValuesCheck"/>

    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <label for="SetOutputCurrentPP" class="control-label">Set Output Current PP:</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-1">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-5 form-inline">
        <label for="SetOutputCurrentPPLowValue" class="control-label">OutputCurrentPPLowValue: </label>&nbsp;

        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="iCheck: $root.regData().setOutputCurrentPPLowValue, enable:  $root.regData().setAlarmValues()" class="large-check" id="SetOutputCurrentPPLowValue"/>
        <input type="text" id="OutputCurrentPPLowValue" data-bind="value: $root.regData().outputCurrentPPLowValue, enable: $root.regData().setOutputCurrentPPLowValue()" class="form-control" maxlength="30" />

      </div>
    </div>
    <br />

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-1">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-5 form-inline">
        <label for="SetOutputCurrentPPHighValue" class="control-label">OutputCurrentPPHighValue:</label>

        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="iCheck: $root.regData().setOutputCurrentPPHighValue, enable: $root.regData().setAlarmValues()" class="large-check" id="SetOutputCurrentPPHighValue"/>
        <input type="text" id="OutputCurrentPPHighValue" data-bind="value: $root.regData().outputCurrentPPHighValue, enable:$root.regData().setOutputCurrentPPHighValue()" class="form-control" maxlength="30" />

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- /ko -->
```

Here is the js:

```
function Registration() {
  var self = this;
  //Alarms
  self.setAlarmValues = ko.observable(false);
  self.setOutputCurrentPPLowValue = ko.observable(false);
  self.setOutputCurrentPPHighValue = ko.observable(false);
  self.outputCurrentPPLowValue = ko.observable("");
  self.outputCurrentPPHighValue = ko.observable("");

}



var registerVM = function() {
  self = this;

  self.validation = ko.observableArray([]);
  self.savingData = ko.observable(false);
  self.regData = ko.observable(new Registration());


ko.bindingHandlers.iCheck = {
  init: function(el, valueAccessor) {
    var observable = valueAccessor();
    $(el).on("ifChanged", function() {
      observable(this.checked);
    });
  },

  update: function(el, valueAccessor) {
    var val = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
    if (val) {
      $(el).iCheck('check');
    } else {
      $(el).iCheck('uncheck');
    }
  }
};

var vm = new registerVM();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Checkbox doesn't enable fields Knockout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65688139/checkbox-doesnt-enable-fields-knockout)

Comment: @Sam That was me who created that question and solved that problem by adding iCheck, but then it created this problem. :(

Comment: maybe you should create a compact working-to-the-point-of-issue code example or fiddle, without all those resource references and whatnot. people are much more prone to help if they don't have to dig through all the clutter.

what exactly needs to be done? enable the two checkboxes whenever the first one is true, and disable and decheck when the first one is false?

Comment: @Sam thanks for the suggestion. I have added a photo too in the question to make it easier to understand my issue.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at the following; I have added the "checked" bindingHandler to your checkboxes and everything looks like it's working. I'm assuming you'll need that icheck bindingHandler to work with that custom js library.

```js
function Registration() {
  var self = this;
  //Alarms
  self.setAlarmValues = ko.observable(false);
  self.setOutputCurrentPPLowValue = ko.observable(false);
  self.setOutputCurrentPPHighValue = ko.observable(false);
  self.outputCurrentPPLowValue = ko.observable("");
  self.outputCurrentPPHighValue = ko.observable("");
}



var registerVM = function() {
  self = this;

  self.validation = ko.observableArray([]);
  self.savingData = ko.observable(false);
  self.regData = ko.observable(new Registration());
}

ko.bindingHandlers.iCheck = {
  init: function(el, valueAccessor) {
    var observable = valueAccessor();
    $(el).on("ifChanged", function() {
      observable(this.checked);
    });
  },

  update: function(el, valueAccessor) {
    var val = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
    if (val) {
      $(el).iCheck('check');
    } else {
      $(el).iCheck('uncheck');
    }
  }
};

var vm = new registerVM();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/iCheck/1.0.3/icheck.min.js"></script>
<!-- ko with: $root.regData -->

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <label for="SetAlarmValues" class="control-label">@MSL.Core.Resource.Models.Well.SetAlarmValues:</label>
      <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: $root.regData().setAlarmValues, iCheck: $root.regData().setAlarmValues" class="large-check" id="SetAlarmValuesCheck" title="@MSL.Core.Resource.Models.Well.SetAlarmValues" />

    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <label for="SetOutputCurrentPP" class="control-label">Set Output Current PP:</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-1">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-5 form-inline">
        <label for="SetOutputCurrentPPLowValue" class="control-label">@MSL.Core.Resource.Models.Well.OutputCurrentPPLowValue: </label>&nbsp;

        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: $root.regData().setOutputCurrentPPLowValue, iCheck: $root.regData().setOutputCurrentPPLowValue, enable:  $root.regData().setAlarmValues()" class="large-check" id="SetOutputCurrentPPLowValue" title="@MSL.Core.Resource.Models.Well.SetOutputCurrentPPLowValue" />
        <input type="text" id="OutputCurrentPPLowValue" data-bind="value: $root.regData().outputCurrentPPLowValue, enable: $root.regData().setOutputCurrentPPLowValue()" class="form-control" maxlength="30" />

      </div>
    </div>
    <br />

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-1">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-5 form-inline">
        <label for="SetOutputCurrentPPHighValue" class="control-label">@MSL.Core.Resource.Models.Well.OutputCurrentPPHighValue:</label>

        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: $root.regData().setOutputCurrentPPHighValue, iCheck: $root.regData().setOutputCurrentPPHighValue, enable: $root.regData().setAlarmValues()" class="large-check" id="SetOutputCurrentPPHighValue" title="@MSL.Core.Resource.Models.Well.SetOutputCurrentPPHighValue" />
        <input type="text" id="OutputCurrentPPHighValue" data-bind="value: $root.regData().outputCurrentPPHighValue, enable:$root.regData().setOutputCurrentPPHighValue()" class="form-control" maxlength="30" />

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: I can see it works in your snippet but it doesn't fix it on my local. I've added a photo in the question so you can see exactly how it looks like with both my original code and your suggestion as well.

Comment: if my snippet works the way you'd want it on your local code then there's something else in your local code interfering with this part, I suggest you start on a clean page in your site with as few as possible other things and try this snippet first, if it works then you can continue adding the other required functionality and work your way up, the culprit will present itself by inclusion.